# jQuery do not redirect after triggering Flask route

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, flask

I have a small Flask app that estimating clusters in my data.
the / route presents the estimated cluster and holds a button updating the clusters if new data arrives. 
The estimation of the clusters happens on /clusterestimation. 
My goal is to trigger /clusterestimation with the button and afterwards redirect to /index such that the presentation of the clusters gets updated as well. 
Unfortunately, the presentation do not update on /index after pressing the bottom. Only when I refresh the page. 
My code looks as follows:

```
$("document").ready(function() 
{$("#btn").click(function()
{window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/clusterestimation"  
})
})
```

And for the Flask part:

```
@app.route('/')
def show_index():
    import os
    images=os.listdir(app.root_path+"/static/img/")
    return render_template("cluster_images.html", cluster_images = images)



@app.route('/clusterestimation')
def clusterestimation():

    ## Doing a some clustering

    return redirect(url_for('show_index'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("#btn_parent").on("click","#btn",function(){ 
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/clusterestimation"  
  });
});
```

or just

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on("click",function(){ 
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/clusterestimation"  
  });
});
```

Using `on` helps when the element you want to attach an event handler to is dynamically generated.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Also, you'll want to double check that `jQuery` is available as `$`, rather than just `jQuery`